# TypeScript Conditional type extends object, available only properties

Tags: typescript

I want to achieve conditional behavior of type. When I put generic in form of object kind (array, object, tuple, record), really any composite type, then I want the type behave as a typeof field of this object, but when the given type is a primary, I want to be the same type.

```
type B<A> = A extends object ? A[keyof A] : A;
const tuple: [1, 2];
const element:B<typeof tuple> = 2; // # ISSUE - element can be also any method of array

const num: 1;
const numElment:B<typeof num> = 1;
```

Above code works but for composite `B` type enables me to assign also all method types from an Array type. My question is - how can I specify that I am interested only about things which are not functions. So only pure fields, as in example with the tuple, `element` should be only number.

I was trying also with `extends {}` or `extends {[a: string | number]: any}` but it was also not working, and even above snippet would break after that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to exclude functions from a type union you can do it with the [`Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu):

```
type ExcludeFunctionProps<T extends object> = Exclude<T[keyof T], Function>;
```

But I don't think this really does what you want:

```
type Hmm = ExcludeFunctionProps<["a", "b"]>; // "a" | "b" | 2
```

Here `Hmm` is `"a" | "b" | 2`.  Why `2`?  Because arrays have a `length` property of a numeric type, and a pair tuple has that type as the numeric literal type `2`.  Unless you intend to include the tuple length, this is probably not the way to go.

```
type EvenWeirder = ExcludeFunctionProps<[string, () => void]>; // string | 2
```

And in the case where the tuple or object explicitly contains function-like values, this would also cut them out.  Definitely seems like strange behavior to me.

---

Instead, I think that you're running into [the issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995) where `keyof T` for an array type is still the full list of all array methods and properties even though you can [map over array types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) without them.  So what I'd try here is to make my own `KeyofAfterMapping<T>` which returns `keyof T` for non-array types, but only keeps the `number` index key for array types.  Like this:

```
type KeyofAfterMapping<T> = Extract<
  keyof T,
  T extends any[] ? number : unknown
>;
```

Let's see what it does:

```
type KeyofPair = KeyofAfterMapping<["a", "b"]>; // number
type KeyofArray = KeyofAfterMapping<string[]>; // number
type KeyofObject = KeyofAfterMapping<{ a: string; b: number }>; // "a" | "b"
```

Now we can specify `B`:

```
type B<A> = A extends object ? A[KeyofAfterMapping<A>] : A;
```

And verify that it behaves as you expect:

```
type TryTupleAgain = B<["a", "b"]>; // "a" | "b"
type KeepsFunctions = B<Array<() => void>>; // () => void
type ObjectsAreStillFine = B<{ a: string; b: number }>; // string | number
type PrimitivesAreStillFine = B<string>; // string
```

Looks good.  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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-aQfAc7PmLVa+rb7Y7PNEasFQuk4wm+qYTdrzUoZeRyD5cmJS53yza7Q7nrQQY7ow3Ik3E628x29XwBIt+x3LdbK6OnQBvJYpifPQHcFOzvpQAC+06ifiSgS8uegRVoMpdSpDrHYnB4-HwUAKMrSAOG4ViO1avnUKYysY87QPQ5AgPQfKtDKbRFkSYjPlU-gJPWgLpNEd5BLB7YQDQFxrJwmEvt2va0B8XxQIiaCCNeDHwkxvxoCRS6-sA1BdhAkKEEgSCYE80DUXuPgHg8jrHqe8aJpe16Hm0SRnuQJEUAQViUgQOwCViwkEKJ4k4JJxTjnJzyqTZbRGEAA)

Comment: Nice one. For now only +. Need to check if this will work. Thank you